# Is there a way to deploy a terraform file via an AWS lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

As the title suggests I am looking for a way to deploy a terraform file via an AWS lambda function. I would like to deploy this file via a time-based event. This is my first time working with terraform and I cannot seem to find anything pertaining to this specific use case.

I am much more versed in CloudFormation so normally what I would do is use the boto3 library to set up a lambda function that would deploy a CloudFormation stack. Does anyone know how to do this with a terraform file?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a custom container deployment in Lambda, and bundle the terraform executable in that container. Note: This is the sort of thing that is generally better to do in an AWS CodeDeploy task than AWS Lambda.

Comment: ahh got it thanks! I'll dig more into this