# How to run terraform apply inside an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I came accross an older [repo](https://github.com/FitnessKeeper/terraform-lambda) on github that seems like it's exactly what I need for my use case. Unfortunately, the code needs to be updated because lambda and/or python no longer support certain opperations.

I keep getting `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/tmpg4l5twh9/terraform'` when I try to execute `terraform --version`. (I get the same error in my local environment and when the lambda function is packaged and deployed to AWS).

Here is my updated sandbox code to update the lambda function:

```
import os
import subprocess
import urllib.request
import tarfile
import json
import tempfile

# Fetch the latest version of Terraform
URL = 'https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/terraform/releases/latest'
with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as response:
    data = response.read()
    encoding = response.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
    TERRAFORM_DOWNLOAD_URL = json.loads(data.decode(encoding))['tarball_url']

# Download and extract the latest version of Terraform
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    TERRAFORM_TAR_PATH = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'terraform.tar.gz')
    TERRAFORM_PATH = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'terraform')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(TERRAFORM_DOWNLOAD_URL, TERRAFORM_TAR_PATH)
    with tarfile.open(TERRAFORM_TAR_PATH, "r:gz") as tf:
        print(f"Extracting {TERRAFORM_TAR_PATH} to {TERRAFORM_PATH}")
        tf.extractall(path=tmpdir)

    # Remove the tar file after it's extracted
    os.remove(TERRAFORM_TAR_PATH)
    print(f"All files extracted to {TERRAFORM_PATH}")
    print(f"{TERRAFORM_PATH} contents: {os.listdir(tmpdir)}")

    # Add Terraform to PATH
    os.rename(f'{tmpdir}/{os.listdir(tmpdir)[0]}', TERRAFORM_PATH)
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + TERRAFORM_PATH
    os.chmod(TERRAFORM_PATH, 0o777)
    # os.system(f'chmod -R 777 {TERRAFORM_PATH}')
    print(os.listdir(TERRAFORM_PATH))
    subprocess.check_output([TERRAFORM_PATH, "--version"])
```

I dont believe this is a duplicate of [Is there a way to deploy a terraform file via an AWS lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804942/is-there-a-way-to-deploy-a-terraform-file-via-an-aws-lambda-function) because I am working from a solution that was previously working.

Comment: Why are you doing this in a lambda function?

Comment: It seemed like the most straightforward way for my use case. I've never used aws code deploy but I'm looking into how to use it and whether or not it is available in GovCloud and other iso regions

Comment: CodeDeploy is almost certainly the better service to use for this type of thing.

Comment: Yes, use code deploy with remote terraform state

Comment: A lot of sources are suggesting the same but I'm not deploying an application... rather I'm deploying s3 configs (via terraform) to tenant-owned aws accounts. most of what I've found expects the deployment to target an ec2 or ecs resource.

Comment: @Paolo, thanks but I dont really know what that means. I'm new to terraform as well and have never used codedeply.

Comment: CodeDeploy is another AWS service which is tailored as the name suggest for deployment. Using a Lambda function is an anti-pattern and could lead to some unwanted results.

Comment: Is there a way to include local files for the buildspec.yml file to use?

Comment: Can you add the output of the `print(oct(os.lstat(TERRAFORM_PATH).st_mode))` to show that the `chmod` took place?

Comment: output for that is `0o40775`. That seems odd since that not the permissions that were set but 775 should still work right?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using codebuild as suggested but it still seems like lambda is viable.

### codebuild.tf

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "on_success" {
  name         = "${random_pet.generator.id}-on-success"
  description  = "CodeBuild project for applying Terraform plans"
  service_role = aws_iam_role.<ROLE_NAME>.arn

  environment {
    compute_type = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image        = "hashicorp/terraform:latest"
    # image        = "public.ecr.aws/hashicorp/terraform:latest"
    type = "LINUX_CONTAINER"

    environment_variable {
      name  = "S3_SAUCE_BUCKET_ID"
      value = aws_s3_bucket.sauce.id
    }

    environment_variable {
      name  = "TF_PACKAGE_NAME"
      value = var.TF_PACKAGE_NAME
    }
  }

  source {
    type      = "NO_SOURCE"
    buildspec = file("buildspec.yml")
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
  }

  cache {
    type  = "LOCAL"
    modes = ["LOCAL_DOCKER_LAYER_CACHE"]
  }

  # This file will be available to the buildspec.yml phases
  secondary_sources {
    source_identifier = "local"
    type              = "S3"
    location          = "${aws_s3_object.on_success.bucket}/${aws_s3_object.on_success.key}"
  }
}
```

### data.tf

```
locals {
  outputs = {
    ON_SUCCESS_IAM_ROLE        = aws_iam_role.<ROLE_NAME>.arn
    S3_SAUCE_BUCKET_ID         = aws_s3_bucket.<BUCKET>.id
    S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET_ARN  = aws_s3_bucket.<BUCKET>.arn
    AWS_DESTINATION_ACCOUNT_ID = data.aws_caller_identity.destination.account_id
  }
}
resource "local_file" "on_success_variables" {
  filename = "${path.root}/modules/on_success/${var.ON_SUCCESS_VARS_FILE}"
  content  = <<-EOT
  %{for key, value in local.outputs~}
  ${key}="${value}"
  %{endfor~}
  EOT
}
data "archive_file" "on_success" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.root}/modules/on_success"
  output_path = "${path.root}/tmp/${var.TF_PACKAGE_NAME}"
  # excludes    = fileset("${path.root}/modules/on_success/", "*.zip")
  excludes = setunion(fileset("${path.root}/modules/on_success", "*.zip"), [".terraform", ".git", ".scripts", ".vscode"])
}
```

### buildspec.yml

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - cd "$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/s3/01"
      - terraform init
      - terraform apply -auto-approve
```